# Integration gmap3 JS plugin with gpxviewer/loadgpx module? How to get 'map' object from gmap3?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, gpx

I am trying to integrate gmap3 JS plugin

http://gmap3.net/

with the gpxviewer module

https://github.com/peplin/gpxviewer

The gpxviewer documentation uses

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
    mapOptions);
loadGPXFileIntoGoogleMap(map, "pocotrail.xml");
```

for creating the map however gmap3 uses the following code generating the map

```
$("#test").gmap3();
```

So how do I get the real **map** object from gmap3 for passing it to loadGPXFileIntoGoogleMap() ?

Comment: use `get` ... see docs: http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/16-misc/get-61

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would do the trick:

```
var map = $("#test").gmap3("get");
```